# Recurrence and measure

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

I was asked to prove this:

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure in $[0,1]$ and $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ a measurable bijection , $\mu([0,1])=1$ and $A\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $\mu(A)>0$.

Find conditions on the measure such that there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\mu(A\cap T^n(A))>0$.
Under such conditions prove or give a counterexample the following:

For all positive integer $k$ there exists another positive integer $n$ such that $\mu(A\cap T^k(A)\cap T^{2k}(A)\cap\dots\cap T^{nk}(A))>0$.

I have been looking for help and I have found Poincaré Recurrence Theorem and Fustenberg's  one, but I don`t know very well how to link them with what I want to prove.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that one of the hypothesis of Poincaré Recurrence is that the bijection T is measure preserving but I don't have that hypothesis in my exercise

Comment: Maybe the intended answer to the "find conditions" part of the question is "$\mu$ is $T$-invariant" so you can use the theorems you mention (...though, that would be odd, since Furstenberg's theorem is, to say the least, rather difficult to prove, so it would be strange to ask it as a question?). You might also consider going back to whoever asked you this question for clarification - it seems like the question you were asked is not so clear.